# How reuse logic for sorting in ascending and descending in angular typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sorting

I am working on angular app where I am able to sort data in ascending and descending order.Though everything is working fine I want to optimise my code so that I don't repeat myself and write an efficient code.

Here is my sample data in console
[sample data in console](https://angular-rxjs-operators-examples.stackblitz.io/stackoverflow)

I have array of object where I want to sort data in ascending and descending order of onclick.Everytime I am calling a function for every field.Is there a better way to do it

Here is my code

**data.ts**

```
 sortedData
]
 private isAscendingSort: boolean = false;

 sortByMaxCases(sortedDataBasedOnDate) {
    this.isAscendingSort = !this.isAscendingSort;
    console.log(this.isAscendingSort)
    sortedDataBasedOnDate.forEach(item => item.statewise.sort(function (a, b) {
      if (b.confirmed < a.confirmed) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (b.confirmed > a.confirmed) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    }))

    if (!this.isAscendingSort) {
      console.log(this.isAscendingSort)
      sortedDataBasedOnDate.forEach(item => item.statewise.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a.confirmed < b.confirmed) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (a.confirmed > b.confirmed) {
          return 1;
        }
        return 0;
      }))

    }
  }

// similary I have 
sortAscendingActive(sortedData)(){..}  // here with same logic compairig a.active > b.active
sortAscendingActive(sortedData){....} // compairig a.confirm > b.confirm
sortAscendingActive(sortedData){..} // compairig a.death> b.death
```

**data.component.html**

```
<tr>
   <th (click)="sortAscending(sortedData)">    State   </th>
   <th (click)="sortAscendingActive(sortedData)">   Active Cases  </th>
   <th (click)="sortAscendingConfirmed(sortedData)"> Confirmed Cases  </th>
   <th (click)="sortAscendingDeath(sortedData)">   Death  </th>
</tr>
```

Here I am getting whole  data in SortedData and then I am performing sorting on click of function but this looks so clumsy.Is there a better way to make my code Efficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the variables as string and access them using square brackets

```html
<tr>
  <th (click)="sort('state')">    State   </th>
  <th (click)="sort('active')">   Active Cases  </th>
  <th (click)="sort('confirmed')"> Confirmed Cases  </th>
  <th (click)="sort('deaths')">   Death  </th>
</tr>
```

```
export class AppComponent {
  stateAsc: boolean = false;
  activeAsc: boolean = false;
  confirmedAsc: boolean = false;
  deathAsc: boolean = false;


  sort = variable => {
    // we can access the value like this using square bracket
    console.log(this[`${variable}Asc`])
    // or you can remove Asc from suffix and access like `this[variable]`

    this.data[0] = {
      ...this.data[0],
      statewise: variable === 'state' // Alphabets needed to sort differently
        ? this.data[0].statewise.sort((a, b) => 
          this.stateAsc 
            ? (a.state > b.state ? -1 : 1) 
            : (b.state > a.state ? -1 : 1)
        )
        : this.data[0].statewise.sort((a, b) => 
            this[`${variable}Asc`] 
             ? a[variable] - b[variable] 
             : b[variable] - a[variable]
        )
    }
    // Change the boolean value
    this[`${variable}Asc`] = !this[`${variable}Asc`]
  }
}
```

[Here is the codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-resonance-gsnx0)

Comment: Still not workking can you show some working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-operators-examples?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstackoverflow%2Fmerge-map-error%2Fmerge-map-error.component.ts here @Vijay

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use something like this. Pass the filed also that you want to sort on.

I haven't handled what the value of isAscending should be. I think you can figure that out.

```
sortDataByField(sortedDataBasedOnDate, fieldName, isAscending) {
      sortedDataBasedOnDate.forEach(item => item.statewise.sort(function (a, b) {
          return (a[fieldName] - b[fieldName]) * (isAscending ? 1 : -1);
      }));
}

sortDataByField(sortedData, 'confirmed', true);
sortDataByField(sortedData, 'active', true);
sortDataByField(sortedData, 'death', true);
```

Comment: not working If possible can you shww a working demo at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-operators-examples?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstackoverflow%2Fmerge-map-error%2Fmerge-map-error.component.ts @Tanmay

Comment: can you send me how the data is? then I can create a demo for you.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/github/mehulk05/COVOID-19 here is my link